# Is there a way to control what Google see when they index a community/site?

Tags: site.com, google

Our community is public, and shared to the world.
However, when it's access/displayed as a result in 'Google', the text under the site name/link is wrong.

[image]

Where is this coming from on the site setup?
how do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Within the Experience Builder, head to:

Experience Builder > Pages > (Page) > Properties > SEO

There you may assign static or dynamic values per page.

Examples:

- Title: `{!Record._Title}`
- HEAD Tags: `<meta property="og:title" content="{!Record._Title}" />`

Also be aware that pages vs records/listings have SEO information applied differently, and if you create a VisualForce page that loads record information dynamically, rather than using Salesforce's built-in Object page feature, you will not be able to effectively use SEO/Meta/OpenGraph information on a page-by-page, listing-bt-listing, basis.